# Use Specifications to execute Queries with IGNITE

Tags: spring-data, ignite

I'm creating a project with Ignite and Spring Data, and I need create a dynamic query using specifications.

I receive  filters (query parsm) from my controller and I have to create the query with that values (some values can be null, so I'm going to use just values with value).

I have tried generate with spring data making use of criteria queries but I did not get.

Anybody knows any way to generate dynamic queries for Ignite ?

I update my question with my code:

After read and investigate, now I have a weird problem if I try to get information by Id using @Query or SqlQuery, I do not get anything, but if I use findById of spring data I get one record. This is my code:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder

public class Availability {

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Long id;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String dateTimeFrom;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String dateTimeTo;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Agenda agenda;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Timetable timetable;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Specialty specialty;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Centre centre;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Room room;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Scope scope;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private Appointment appointment;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String lockedReason;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String initDate;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String endDate;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String initTime;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String endTime;
```

}

This is the way which I try to get the object:

```
    SqlQuery sql2 = new SqlQuery(Availability.class,
    "id = ?");
try (QueryCursor<Entry<Long, Availability>> cursor = cache.query(sql2.setArgs(1))) {
  for (Entry<Long, Availability> e : cursor)
    System.out.println(e.getValue().toString());
}
```

The function before return 0 values, but if I use findById(1L) of Spring Data I get one result.

And this is the way which I set the id:

```
Ignition.ignite().atomicSequence("seq", 1, true).getAndIncrement()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you also provide your cache configuration and code, that you use to insert the data?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? This issue doesn't seem to be related to Spring Data, since you cannot get data using regular Ignite SQL. So, I'd like to see, what cache configuration and data entries look like, since the issues is most likely to be there.

Comment: Finally I have changed everything, I use thin client and I have changed my logic, and now everything is working. I was not able to figure out the problem, and I have to use this client because of our platform.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation for Spring Data integration for Apache Ignite: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/spring-data

Also Spring Data documentation can be useful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

If after reading this you still have issues with configuring it properly, then please add code snippets that you try to run, and specify what you expect and what you get.

Comment: I have read everything but I 'm still having problems, I'm going to paste my code